# CROSS COMPILE PHP 5.5.1 for QoriQ P1022 (DS213+) - Fatal error: Balloc() allocation exceeds

Tags: php, cross-compiling, powerpc, synology

I struggled for days with cross compiling php for DS2013+ (QoriQ P1022)

**aim :** being able to leverage pcntl_fork() with php

**means :**

- a compiled version of php configured with : --enable-pcntl
- DSM toolchain 4.1 : http__sourceforge.net/projects/dsgpl/f ... z/download )
- a VM with Debian 32b : ftp__ftp.free.fr/mirrors/ftp.ubuntu.co ... d-i386.iso
- Synology 3rd party instruction PDF : http__usdl.synology.com/download/ds/us ... _Guide.pdf
- php-5.5.11 : http__www.php.net/get/php-5.5.11.tar.gz/from/a/mirror
- php-5.6.0beta1 : http__downloads.php.net/tyrael/php-5.6.0beta1.tar.gz
- my NAS : 213+, with bootstrap modified following online articles and leveraging ipkg repository : http__packages.quadrat4.de/
  So with all the above I intended to cross compile php5.5.1 (or 5.6beta0) on a Debian :

**Problem :** Each time I end up with this error :
Fatal error: Balloc() allocation exceeds list boundary....

**From debian :**

My root working folder : /home/enola/NAS_Compiler/

PhP being uncompress here : 
    /home/enola/NAS_Compiler/PhP/php-5.5.11
    /home/enola/NAS_Compiler/PhP/php-5.6.0beta1

Toolchains : 
    tar -xvzf gcc4374_eglibc2874_qoriq-GPL.tgz
    mv powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe /usr/local/

```
export CC=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-gcc
export CXX=$CC
(also tried with CXX=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux=gnuspe-g++)
(and without it)
export LD=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-ld
export AR=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-ar
export RANLIB=/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/bin/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe-ranlib
export CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/include -mcpu=8548 -mhard-float -mfloat-gprs=double'
(also tried with CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/include')
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe/lib"
```

I tried multiple .configure most simple below:

```
./configure --host=powerpc-unknow-linux --target=powerpc-unknow-linux --build=i686-pc-linux --prefix=/home/enola/NAS_Compiler/usr/local/ --disable-all --with-layout=GNU --enable-debug
```

tried without --with-layout=GNU, --enable-debug) 
also tried with --enable-inline-optimization

```
make CC="${CC}" AR="${AR} r"
```

Once compiled I copy sapi/cli/php to the NAS

**From the DSM (NAS) :**

**PHP 5.5.11**
then execute it :./php -c ./php.ini-simple -f test_microtime.php
Result :
Fatal error: Balloc() allocation exceeds list boundary in ..... test_microtime.php on line 3

**PHP 5.6.0beta0**
then execute it :./php -c ./php.ini-simple -f te
same results... : 
Fatal error: Balloc() allocation exceeds list boundary in.... test_microtime.php on line 3

*test_microtime.php :*

```
<?Php
echo microtime(true);
?>
```

phpscript, strace, php.ini-simple, and php binaries from the above commands..
**are all here :**
http://www.mobilutils.com/20140423_sentToForum.zip

*SHA1 : (20140423_sentToForum.zip)= 5a04cb7015c28d798ac2446e14fd9c114f47a660*

with some research I found this and others with not a clue on how to solve the issue :( : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47980

so I am writing this in case one of you have a clue on what I am doing wrong...
open to any suggestions advice that might help solving this,

PS : I thought everything was working like a charm until I tried time functions :)....

thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Usually I prefer to run a Linux on a VM that emulates the target machine hardware.
You can also test the binary/things better.

I have used with success the QEMU emulator, with ARM/PowerPC and MIPS targets.

You can also refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430685/1052899) in another thread. Quote:

> QEMU turns your PC in an hypervisor i.e. works like VirtualBox. But
>   QEMU can also emulate CPUs that are different from the host PC one.
>
> You can install and run a PowerPC Linux VM on a standard(cheap) x86 PC
>   and compile your binaries directly in that VM. CPU emulation is a bit slow, but it works.