# Building for PowerPC 405 machine running Linux 2.4.18 with a Mac G4 running 2.4.27

Tags: linux, kernel, powerpc

I presently run Linux 2.4.27 (Debian Sarge) on a PowerPC Mac G4 machine. I need to write software for Linux 2.4.18 running on a PowerPC 405 machine, and the binaries I am producing on my Mac G4 running 2.4.27 with both GCC 3.3.5 and GCC 2.95.3 (I have both installed) are having problems; I have built a static version of cURL with both compilers that segfaults when run on this 2.4.18 PowerPC 405 machine. I have noticed that binaries built on a 2.4.18 kernel with a cross compiler work (x86->PPC), however. Unfortunately, the machine that makes those binaries is unavailable to me, and I am really trying to get the Mac to be the "one stop shop" in this development effort (I want to be able to test and run on this machine).

I cannot find a 2.4.18 distribution of Linux for PowerPC anywhere. What can I do to build binaries that will work on a PowerPC 405 machine running Linux 2.4.18 given a PowerPC Mac G4 running a 2.4.27 kernel? Is building GLIBC for 2.2.5 and setting the compilers to use it the answer, or do I have to somehow build a whole kernel of 2.4.18 to support what I am trying to do?

Comment: Powerpc G4 != Powerpc 405. You are trying to use the compiler for the G4 to generate binaries for the 405. These will not work. At work, I have separate compilers for 74xx (G4) and 405. You should build a cross compiler on your G4 that will output PPC405 mnemonics.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will look into a cross compiler for PPC 405. Can you make your comment an answer to my question? I'd like to give you credit if your suggestion is the solution to my problem. I hope I did not somehow block answers from being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several weeks later, it appears that the solution suggested by user sessyargc.jp was indeed to use a cross compiler. I am accepting my answer only because I want to close this question out and I can find no way to give sessyargc.jp credit, since he/she only made a comment. Still, thank you sessyargc.jp for pointing the way!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in the past, I used the **QEMU** emulator on my x86 machine.

QEMU emulates the *PowerPC-405* CPU too, here is the list of emulated PowerPC CPUs https://github.com/hackndev/qemu/blob/master/target-ppc/STATUS.

QEMU turns your PC in an hypervisor i.e. works like *VirtualBox*. But QEMU can also emulate CPUs that are different from the host PC one.

You can install and run a PowerPC Linux VM on a standard(cheap) x86 PC and compile your binaries directly in that VM. CPU emulation is a bit slow, but it works.

Regards